# ArcObjects: Custom GP tools: GPCompositeDataType and DataType

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I got an issue with the parameter value's datatype returned when using composite type parameters. In my case, I create a composite of DEWorkspaceType and DEFeatureClassType:

```
IGPCompositeDataType gpCompositeDataType = new GPCompositeDataTypeClass();
gpCompositeDataType.AddDataType(new DEWorkspaceTypeClass());
gpCompositeDataType.AddDataType(new DEFeatureClassTypeClass());
```

No matter what I select in my tool, e.g .gdb, .shp etc, I get "DEWorkspaceType" in the unpacked IGPValue.DataType.

If I switch the sequence of the types, using DEFeatureClassTypeClass as the first datatype in the composite, I get DEFeatureClass as the parameter value type.. no matter what I select in the dialog.

Am I left with parsing/guessing the datatype in the string from IGPValue.GetAsText() ?

(version: 10.0 SP5)

Comment: Seems like a bug. You can always check what type the resulting `IGPValue` is by querying for implemented interfaces, such as [IDEFeatureClass](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000194000000) or [IDEWorkspace3](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000nt2000000) . Will that do the trick?

Comment: DIM SUM as (new DEWorkspaceTypeClass());=(new DEFeatureClassTypeClass()); ??

Comment: @PetrKrebs, i tried both "if (val is IDEFeatureDatasetType)" and checking the name of the IGPValue.DataType.Name without any luck.